# Apache Superset latest version between 0.38.1 and 1.0.1

Tags: apache-superset

Looking at [Apache Superset releases](https://github.com/apache/superset/releases) on Github, I can't figure out if version *0.38.1* and version *1.0.1* are related or not.

If they are related, why *0.38.1* comes after *1.0.1*?

Can you confirm that the latest version is 0.38.1?